# How to combine OpenVPN and hostapd on a single raspberry pi?

Tags: routes, openvpn, hostapd

I had my Pi configured as an OpenVPN server for access to my local network when not at home.
It worked like a charm :-)

Now I also want to use my Pi as an access point.

For this I used the following instructions:
[Setting up a Bridged Wireless Access Point](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#setting-up-a-bridged-wireless-access-point)

(Almost) everything seems to work fine. The 'access point' function as it should be and I can also set up an OpenVPN tunnel.

I can access my **local** devices with my client through that tunnel. However, as soon as the VPN tunnel is active, I can no longer access 'the internet' with that client.
I can't load web pages, but I can't ping either. Pinging to 142.250.179.163 (= [www.google.nl](http://www.google.nl)) only returns a timeout.

There seems to be something wrong in routing the traffic, but I'm a little short on knowledge to solve the problem.
hopefully somebody can help me.

This is my configuration:

**OpenVPN:**

/etc/openvpn/server.conf

```
dev tun
proto udp
port 1194
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued/raspberrypi_foo-foo.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/raspberrypi_foo-foo.key
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
# Set your primary domain name server address for clients
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
# Prevent DNS leaks on Windows
push "block-outside-dns"
# Override the Client default gateway by using 0.0.0.0/1 and
# 128.0.0.0/1 rather than 0.0.0.0/0. This has the benefit of
# overriding but not wiping out the original default gateway.
push "redirect-gateway def1"
client-to-client
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
keepalive 15 120
remote-cert-tls client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-crypt /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ta.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
user openvpn
group openvpn
persist-key
persist-tun
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20
status-version 3
syslog
verb 3
#DuplicateCNs allow access control on a less-granular, per user basis.
#Remove # if you will manage access by user instead of device. 
#duplicate-cn
# Generated for use by PiVPN.io
```

**hostapd:**

/etc/systemd/network/bridge-br0.netdev

```
[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge
```

/etc/systemd/network/br0-member-eth0.network

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Bridge=br0
```

/etc/dhcpcd.conf

```
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
# Some non-RFC compliant DHCP servers do not reply with this set.
# In this case, comment out duid and enable clientid above.
#duid

# Stop dhcpcd (to bridge wlan0 to eth0)
denyinterfaces wlan0 eth0

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# Most distributions have NTP support.
#option ntp_servers

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate SLAAC address using the Hardware Address of the interface
#slaac hwaddr
# OR generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses based from the DUID
slaac private

# Example static IP configuration:
#interface eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
#static ip6_address=fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::ff/64
#static routers=192.168.0.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::1

# It is possible to fall back to a static IP if DHCP fails:
# define static profile
#profile static_eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.1.23/24
#static routers=192.168.1.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1

# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0

# Connect to bridge 
interface br0
```

/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

```
country_code=NL
interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
ssid=Charon
hw_mode=g
channel=3
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=foo-foo
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it is simple... (it Always is !)

Just add a default route to the router at the interface br0:

/etc/dhcpcd.conf

```
(...)
# Connect to bridge 
interface br0
# Default route
static routers=192.168.1.254
```